# Java Synthesizer Programming

Tags: java, envelope, synthesizer, javax.sound.sampled

I'm trying to learn to create a Synthesizer from scratch using Java I tried stringing together some tutorials and code to try and learn from a basic working product but I'm not getting any sound. I just want to be able to generate sound using sin, saw, and square waves. When I run the program I'm getting no sound. I think my problems are in the Main.java class and the SamplePlayer.java class. I get an error in the SamplePlayer.java class which I will post at the end. Does anyone know what I am doing wrong or what needs to be changed in order to create a basic sound?

I have 6 classes:

- Envelope.java (Sets up the ADSR envelope generator)
- Main.java (contains main function)

  ```
  public class Main
  {
      public static void main(String[] args) 
      {
      // Create an oscillator sample producer
      Oscillator osc = new Oscillator();

      // Set the frequency
      osc.setFrequency(500);

      // Set the waveashape
      //osc.setWaveshape(WAVESHAPE.SIN);

      // Create a sample player
      SamplePlayer player = new SamplePlayer();

      // Sets the player's sample provider
      player.setSampleProvider(osc);

      // Start the player
      player.startPlayer();

      // Delay so oscillator can be heard
      try
      {
          TimeUnit.SECONDS.sleep(4);  
      }
      catch(InterruptedException e)
      {

      }

      // Stop the player
      player.stopPlayer();
  }

  }
  ```
- SamplePlayer.java (In charge of sampling the waves and playing the sound)

  ```
  import java.nio.ByteBuffer;

  import javax.sound.sampled.AudioFormat;
  import javax.sound.sampled.AudioSystem;
  import javax.sound.sampled.DataLine;
  import javax.sound.sampled.SourceDataLine;

  public class SamplePlayer extends Thread 
  {

      // AudioFormat parameters
      public  static final int     SAMPLE_RATE = 22050;
      private static final int     SAMPLE_SIZE = 16;
      private static final int     CHANNELS = 1;
      private static final boolean SIGNED = true;
      private static final boolean BIG_ENDIAN = true;

      // Chunk of audio processed at one time
      public static final int BUFFER_SIZE = 1000;
      public static final int SAMPLES_PER_BUFFER = BUFFER_SIZE / 2;

      public SamplePlayer() 
      {

          // Create the audio format we wish to use
          format = new AudioFormat(SAMPLE_RATE, SAMPLE_SIZE, CHANNELS, SIGNED, BIG_ENDIAN);

          // Create dataline info object describing line format
          info = new DataLine.Info(SourceDataLine.class, format);
      }

      public void run() 
      {

          done = false;
          int nBytesRead = 0;

          try 
          {
              // Get line to write data to
              auline = (SourceDataLine) AudioSystem.getLine(info);
              auline.open(format);
              auline.start();

              while ((nBytesRead != -1) && (! done)) 
              {
                  nBytesRead = getSamples(sampleData);
                  if (nBytesRead > 0) {
                      auline.write(sampleData, 0, nBytesRead);
                  }
              }

          } catch(Exception e) 
          {
              e.printStackTrace();                
          } finally {
              auline.drain();
              auline.close();                         
          }
      }       

      public void startPlayer() 
      {
          if (provider != null) 
          {
              start();    
          }
      }

      public void stopPlayer() 
      {
          done = true;
      }

      public void setSampleProvider(SampleProviderIntfc provider) 
      {
          this.provider = provider;
      }
      public int getSamples(byte [] samples)
      {
          return ByteBuffer.wrap(samples).getInt();
      }

      // Instance data
      private AudioFormat format;
      private DataLine.Info info;
      private SourceDataLine auline;
      private boolean done;
      private byte [] sampleData = new byte[BUFFER_SIZE];
      private SampleProviderIntfc provider;
  }
  ```
- SampleProviderIntfc.java (has a getSamples() method stub)

Error generated in SamplePlayer.java:

```
2015-11-12 00:37:22.215 java[892:2167212] Error loading /Library/Audio/Plug-Ins/HAL/SeratoVirtualAudioPlugIn.plugin/Contents/MacOS/SeratoVirtualAudioPlugIn:  dlopen(/Library/Audio/Plug-Ins/HAL/SeratoVirtualAudioPlugIn.plugin/Contents/MacOS/SeratoVirtualAudioPlugIn, 262): no suitable image found.  Did find:
    /Library/Audio/Plug-Ins/HAL/SeratoVirtualAudioPlugIn.plugin/Contents/MacOS/SeratoVirtualAudioPlugIn: mach-o, but wrong architecture
2015-11-12 00:37:22.215 java[892:2167212] Cannot find function pointer New_SHP_PlugIn for factory 834FC054-C1CC-11D6-BD01-00039315CD46 in CFBundle/CFPlugIn 0x7fd7abd29180 </Library/Audio/Plug-Ins/HAL/SeratoVirtualAudioPlugIn.plugin> (bundle, not loaded)
2015-11-12 00:37:22.253 java[892:2167212] 00:37:22.252 WARNING:  >compload> 472: Kickstart.component -- file://localhost/Library/Audio/Plug-Ins/Components/: trouble parsing Info.plist's AudioComponents, key (null); entry: <CFBasicHash 0x7fd7abc44cc0 [0x7fff73159390]>{type = mutable dict, count = 7,
entries =>
    2 : <CFString 0x7fff730e39f0 [0x7fff73159390]>{contents = "manufacturer"} = <CFString 0x7fd7abc4b9c0 [0x7fff73159390]>{contents = "CaNR"}
    7 : <CFString 0x7fff730e74b0 [0x7fff73159390]>{contents = "factoryFunction"} = <CFString 0x7fd7abc4b090 [0x7fff73159390]>{contents = "KickstartAUFactory"}
    8 : <CFString 0x7fd7abc4baa0 [0x7fff73159390]>{contents = "subtype"} = <CFString 0x7fd7abc4bae0 [0x7fff73159390]>{contents = "CNKS"}
    9 : <CFString 0x7fff7310b6f0 [0x7fff73159390]>{contents = "description"} = <CFString 0x7fd7abc4c180 [0x7fff73159390]>{contents = "Kickstart"}
    10 : <CFString 0x7fff7310a3d0 [0x7fff73159390]>{contents = "type"} = <CFString 0x7fd7abc4bbc0 [0x7fff73159390]>{contents = "kAudioUnitType_Effect"}
    11 : <CFString 0x7fff73095bb0 [0x7fff73159390]>{contents = "name"} = <CFString 0x7fd7abc4b990 [0x7fff73159390]>{contents = "Nicky Romero: Kickstart"}
    12 : <CFString 0x7fff73114370 [0x7fff73159390]>{contents = "version"} = <CFNumber 0x1000937 [0x7fff73159390]>{value = +65545, type = kCFNumberSInt64Type}
}
2015-11-12 00:37:22.256 java[892:2167212] 00:37:22.256 WARNING:  >compload> 472: Primer.component -- file://localhost/Library/Audio/Plug-Ins/Components/: trouble parsing Info.plist's AudioComponents, key (null); entry: <CFBasicHash 0x7fd7abc4b0f0 [0x7fff73159390]>{type = mutable dict, count = 7,
entries =>
    2 : <CFString 0x7fff730e39f0 [0x7fff73159390]>{contents = "manufacturer"} = <CFString 0x7fd7abc4b3e0 [0x7fff73159390]>{contents = "AudG"}
    7 : <CFString 0x7fff730e74b0 [0x7fff73159390]>{contents = "factoryFunction"} = <CFString 0x7fd7abc4b090 [0x7fff73159390]>{contents = "PrimerAUFactory"}
    8 : <CFString 0x7fd7abc4ac30 [0x7fff73159390]>{contents = "subtype"} = <CFString 0x7fd7abc4b990 [0x7fff73159390]>{contents = "agp"}
    9 : <CFString 0x7fff7310b6f0 [0x7fff73159390]>{contents = "description"} = <CFString 0x7fd7abc4af00 [0x7fff73159390]>{contents = "Primer"}
    10 : <CFString 0x7fff7310a3d0 [0x7fff73159390]>{contents = "type"} = <CFString 0x7fd7abc4c4c0 [0x7fff73159390]>{contents = "aumu"}
    11 : <CFString 0x7fff73095bb0 [0x7fff73159390]>{contents = "name"} = <CFString 0x7fd7abc4a1a0 [0x7fff73159390]>{contents = "Audible Genius: Primer"}
    12 : <CFString 0x7fff73114370 [0x7fff73159390]>{contents = "version"} = <CFNumber 0x1010137 [0x7fff73159390]>{value = +65793, type = kCFNumberSInt64Type}
}
```

These errors are generated in the lines:

```
auline = (SourceDataLine) AudioSystem.getLine(info);
auline.open(format);
```

Comment: Please read about how to ask a good question, specifically about posting an [MCVE](http://www.stackoverflow.com/help/mcve).

Comment: Have you tried searching for "mach-o, but wrong architecture" on a search engine of your choice?

Comment: Surely you can reduce the example significantly! Get a minimal repro that you think should work and share that one, not the entire program.